# How to set a transparent navigation bar? iOS 11 swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, swift4

On the picture on the right is what I need and on the left is what I get:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SceOh.jpg)

I'm trying to make a transparent navigation bar, and in the book which I'm reading it's written that all you need to do is to insert this code in viewDidLoad() method of the preferable View Controller:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white

tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

But all I get is a white navigation bar. 
Also if's written that the difference of bars on the picture is in this code:

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

But it doesn't work for me

I downloaded the final project of this book's chapter and everything works fine there, though I've tried to copy-paste the code and still got nothing changed

And the thing is - I've already tried to insert this code:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

> But it doesn't work

If it matters, the book is "Beginning iOS 11 programming" by AppCoda

Comment: @AbhishekMitra not completely, the issue you're referencing is using `.appearance` which is used for the whole app. In this case, it's for a single `ViewController`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following code:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Hope it will help you.

**Edit (UPDATE)**

Use Below Code:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
    }
```

It have to be work.

Comment: I've already tried this. It doesn't help

Comment: I get back the back button but the bar is still white

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков I think that because of your `navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white` this peace of line, do this `navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .clear` and let me know.

Comment: By changing this the back button disappears again, and nav bar is still white

Comment: I've already tried to extend image in storyboard, but the result is the same

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков my mistake `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true` this must be true. I tried my self and working perfectly..

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков Use that code in `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`

Comment: Still get white nav bar with a back button. I'll try to share my Xcode project in a few minutes

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков Block your all code what you have got from here and do my new update 2 in answer. Thanks

Comment: I just get red letters. Nothing else changes

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков yes, it is for tint color. anyway let me share that project with you. it is working fine.

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков here you go to have the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DIsqlbbRclC3ViixnL0RQSp95FMeq--a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok
My project
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/130rTCkGhx89fQst_HLDj5qQuFqX1j5_C

Comment: @ДмитрийМеньшиков make sure that the top most view you are adding, the top constraint shouldn't be set to safe area it should be set to view. Then the above code works fine.

Comment: "Update 2" did the trick on ios 12 swift 4 for iphone XR.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false     
    }
```

Comment: i download your project but main.stroyboard is missing and some other files are missing